# Синтаксический разбор предложения с числительным

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите разобрать предложение по составу: *Ее длина 61 метр.*

Answer (score 2):

***Ее длина 61 метр.***

*Длина* — подлежащее, *61 метр* — составное именное сказуемое (именная часть выражена  числовым оборотом, связка пропущена),  *её* — определение, выраженное притяжательным местоимением.

**Правило постановки тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Розенталь 4. Тире ставится, если оба главных члена предложения выражены количественными числительными или если один из них выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — числительным либо оборотом с числительным: **Скорость — шестьдесят километров в час.**

Примечание. В специальной литературе при характеристике предмета тире в этом случае часто не ставится: **Вылет стрелы 5 метров**;